What is the smallest number of glasses the team can move to perform Coach Newton’s challenge?
Beginner puzzle (suitable for people who are new to puzzle solving)

Coach Newton sets up ten glasses arranged in a triangle as shown, with the glasses numbered 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, and 10 full of water and the others empty. The coach challenges the team to rearrange the glasses into the second configuration shown, with full glasses at positions B, C, E, G, H, and I, and in which the triangle points in the opposite direction.
When moving a glass that contains water you can pour its water into another glass.
What is the smallest number of glasses the team can move to perform Coach Newton’s challenge?



Attribution:  momath.org


 3 moves are enough

by

 * Pour 10 into 6 and place it below 8 and 9 becoming "J". 
 * Pour 7 into 4 and place it left of 2 becoming "A". 
 * Move 1 right of 3  becoming "D".


This is what I wrote in my deleted answer but I thought it was wrong. I am not sure if the letters and numbers correlate

I recall you (or someone else - I can't see deleted answers) was saying 6 moves before they deleted their answer.   the letters are for clarification, I give prosiition relative to numbers,

@PDT Jasen’s answer is correct.

No I had an answer before that one
